# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't boot on Sony Vaio pcg7l1m

Tags: boot, vaio, sony

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Sony Vaio PGN7L1M. My CD drive doesn't work but I have an external connected. I have a boot DVD and a boot USB. Neither will boot. The booting options I can choose in the machine are: Optical Drive, Floppy disk Drive, Hard Disk Drive and Network (I have set them in this order). What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command by plugin the USB drive,

> sudo mkdir /media/floppy

```
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/sdb /media/floppy
```

Comment: Thanks. but that didn't work either. When I reboot it still won't take the usb to boot from.